# how to add a string to end of the path of a naming function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add the current date and time to the end of a file naming path
in a 3D software and I have this so far:

```
#python
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
lx.out(now)
lx.eval("render /Users/me/Desktop/images/")
```

tried this (but didn't work)

```
lx.eval("render /Users/me/Desktop/images/%s" %(now))
```

Comment: What is `lx`?  How did it "not work"?

Comment: it's like trace or print command

Answer (score 0):

You can get a string with the current date and time with:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowString = str(now).replace(" ", "-")
```

You can then add that string to the rest of your path. For instance, using your path above:

```
lx.eval("render /Users/me/Desktop/images/" + nowString)
```

Comment: By the way, of course, you don't need the "replace" bit---it's there just to avoid having spaces in your filenames.

Comment: thnx, but says nowString is not defined

Comment: Did you include the line that starts with `nowString = str(now)`?

Comment: yes, forgot it 1st time, and tried again w it, but now it says "the command doesnt have an argument named */Users/me/Desktop/images/2012-11-7"

Comment: This does not sound like a problem of adding a string with a datetime, but a problem in using the `lx` object properly. Can you get it to store other filenames correctly?

Comment: yes, no spaces. but if I change to ..images/" + str(now) then it says the command doesnt have argument for 22

Comment: yes it stores correctly. basically w/t any str at the end it renders  a file and names it 0001 (for example, its internal) but every time u execute it, it overides the previous file so i'm trying to add a unique file name to each render

Comment: This is most likely an issue with how `lx.eval()` should be called, then, not about including a datetime in a filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the strftime function to properly format the date without spaces. I usually format the date like this, because it appears sorted in your filesystem:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print("render mypath/%s" % now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))
```

Outputs:

```
render mypath/20121208_113754
```